# Can someone help me with Android development login password?

Tags: java, android

Hi i am new to android development I am getting errors, i created to php files in notepad and set the .php at the end. The ui runs fine its just when I click login or the register button it forces close help please

the error log i get is

> ```
> 04-13 12:18:25.811: W/System.err(349): java.net.SocketException: Permission denied 
> 04-13 12:18:25.811: W/System.err(349): 
> at org.apache.harmony.luni.platform.OSNetworkSystem.createStreamSocketImpl(Native Method)
> 04-13 12:18:25.811: W/System.err(349): 
> at org.apache.harmony.luni.platform.OSNetworkSystem.createStreamSocke(OSNetworkSystem.java:186)
> 04-13 12:18:25.811: W/System.err(349): 
> at org.apache.harmony.luni.net.PlainSocketImpl.create(PlainSocketImpl.java:265)
> 04-13 12:18:25.811: W/System.err(349): 
> at java.net.Socket.checkClosedAndCreate(Socket.java:873)
> 04-13 12:18:25.811: W/System.err(349):
> ```

Answer (score 0):

looks like you need to add the `INTERNET` permission in your manifest.

Comment: I already the internet permissions the log error seems to be something from the LoginActivity file, I used the code from the android hive android registration

Comment: Edit your question and Post the code from that activity then, and use a comment to highlight which line the log points to in that file.

Answer (score 0):

usespermission line might be in wrong place in your manifest file.
make sure that it is under manifest tag like this:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.test"
    android:versionCode="5"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Look like your manifest is't configured correctly...

He's something that might help you

[Security and manifest - Android -](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/security/security.html)

```
...
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
...
```

You pretty much simply have to add the above line to you manifest and it should work. Make sure to look at the link for further explanations!

Regards, Erwald